# Where to find OpenSSL devel package - can't seem to find it in Brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, openssl, irc

I'm trying to install openssl-devel on OS X El Capitan, and I can't seem to find the package on Brew nor the source anywhere online. The application I'm installing (UnrealIRCd) requires both openssl and openssl-devel to install. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just install `openssl` via Homebrew. It contains all you need.

EDIT: I tried building UnrealIRCd with `openssl` installed and it built successfully.

EDIT2: On a number of package managers, a software package is divided into runtime (used by other softwares to run) and development (used to build the other softwares) packages.
For instance, `openssl` is a runtime and `openssl-devel` is a development package on those package managers.
However, packages on Homebrew aren't separated in this manner but just contain both.
This is why just installing `openssl` is fine on Homebrew.

Comment: Equal, I am not sure that just installing openssl is going to help as Zulu has said that the package isn't available within brew so the issue is more complex.